# MonoTouch: How to save a huge PDF downloaded from an URL incrementally?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, download, nsdata

I need to download a huge PDF file from an URL in my MonoTouch iPhone/iPad newsstand app.

The PDF is too big to fit in memory, so I need to save it incrementally with NSData.

My idea is the following: instead of appending all the downloaded data in NSData and at the very end of the download, when I got all data, to store it to a file, I want to execute the download asynchronously in a separate thread and append to a file each received chunk and free my memory, but be certain that if the connection is dropped or the app crashes the download would resume automatically from the last chunk without corrupting the file.

What do you suggest? Is there a better method? How can I do it in MonoTouch? I did't find any documentation or code example about iOS incremental download/resume on the Xamarin website.

Comment: I think you need to research how to do this in plain old .Net/C#.  It should be the same on windows as in MonoTouch.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the guidelines indicated by the Apple slides of the Newsstand presentation ("Building Newsstand Apps", Session 504). I just want to understand what C# code in MonoTouch is equivalent to that in Obj-C showed in the slides. Are you sure the standard .NET way is the right way to handle this? Or am I at risk to see my App rejected by Apple? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `NSData` or anything from ObjC.
You can use `WebClient` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to achieve this in plain C#.
For an example of a chunked download with progress bar, see here: http://devtoolshed.com/content/c-download-file-progress-bar

Comment: The article you linked doesn't seem to do what I'm asking, not even in classic C#/.NET way. From one comment: "Looking at the code here this would be completely unsuitable for anything but small files since it creates a byte array the size of the file which leads to pretty bad memory use. Good example code but for real use anyone looking at this code should implement a fixed size buffer and flush the buffer to file and reuse it to grab the next chunk of data." Also using WebClient on MonoTouch is not raccomended (see: http://escoz.com/blog/webclient-reliability-problems-under-monotouch ).

Comment: The comment is from November 2010! Yes, Monotouch/Mono had an issue in the network stack but it is resolved and as Migueal also stated: WebClient is the thing to use. If you want to stick with Apple's guidelines so strictly, you'll have to use ObjC. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Net.WebClient and use the DownloadFile method, which will stream the data from HTTP to disk, without keeping it in memory.

Comment: The Apple slides of the Newsstand presentation ("Building Newsstand Apps", Session 504) raccomends the use of the NSURLConnection Delegate and NKAssetDownload for downloading and resuming the newsstand content. Is it better to follow those guidelines or there is no difference? Thanks!

Comment: I have not watched that presentation, merely answering the original question.   You should post this as a follow up question.

Comment: Ok, I posted a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688197/monotouch-how-to-download-pdf-incrementally-as-indicated-in-the-apple-slides-b